# React component fails to rerender when change button is located in sibling

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

Can someone help me with this puzzle? I have a parent App component and two child components: Form and DataGrid (which are both function components).

Users enter data in the form, press a Submit button and their data is added to the DataGrid. The data is stored as state in the App component and the submit handler is defined in the App component. Everything works fine when the button is in the return value of the App component render method (as a peer of the Form and DataGrid). And it also works if the button is in the return value of the Grid (where the new data appears). But if I put the button in the return value of the Form, the state data change DOES occur, but the Grid component does not re-render, so the new data doesn't appear.

**Why does it matter where the *button* is located?** The data (that is, the state) that is changing and the handler that the button click is tiggering are all in the App component.

```
App
  -Form
    -TextBox
    -RadioButtons
    [-Button (Grid won't re-render if the button is here in sibling of Grid)]

  -Grid
    -Title
    -Table
    [-Button (Grid DOES re-render if the button is here in the Grid)]
 [-Button (Grid also re-renders if the button is up here in the App)]
```

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {dataRows: [["John", "Ladd", "Science Lab", "a"],["Bill", "Smith", "Swimming", "bc"]],
              firstName: "", 
              lastName: "", 
              activity: "", 
              dietary: false,
              disability: false,
              medical: false
             }
this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this)
}
submitData() {
var restrictions = "";
if (this.state.dietary) { restrictions += "a";}
if (this.state.disability) { restrictions += "b";}
if (this.state.medical) { restrictions += "c";}

var newRow = [this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.activity, restrictions] 
var dataCopy = this.state.dataRows.slice()
dataCopy.push(newRow) 
this.setState({dataRows: dataCopy},
             function() {
              // blank out the form
              var startingState = {firstName: "", 
                              lastName: "", 
                              activity: "", 
                              dietary: false,
                              disability: false,
                              medical: false
                             };
              this.setState(startingState)
             }
)
}

render() {    
return <div>
      <RegistrationForm 
        dietary={this.state.dietary}
        disability={this.state.disability}
        medical={this.state.medical}
        firstName={this.state.firstName} 
        lastName={this.state.lastName} 
        activity= {this.state.activity} 
        handleChange={this.handleChange} 
        handleCheckBoxChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange}/>
      <Button label="Submit" submitData={this.submitData} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
      <DataGrid rows={this.state.dataRows} removeRow={this.removeRow} />
    </div>
 }
}

function DataGrid(props) {
var rows = []
for(let i = 0; i < props.rows.length; i++){
    rows.push(<Row key={i} cellValues = {props.rows[i]} removeRow={() => props.removeRow(i) } />)
}
return (<div>              
    <HeaderRow columnLabels={["Remove", "First Name", "Last Name", "Activity", "Restrictions"]}/>
      {rows}
    </div>
)
}

function RegistrationForm(props) {
return <form>
      <TextBox label = "First Name:" name="firstName" value={props.firstName} handleChange={props.handleChange}/>
      <TextBox label = "Last Name:" name="lastName" value={props.lastName} handleChange={props.handleChange}/>
      <DropDown label="Select Activity:" name="activity" value={props.activity} 
        options={["Science Lab", "Swimming", "Cooking", "Painting"]} handleChange={props.handleChange}/>
      <CheckBoxSet label="Check all that apply:" name="restrictions" 
        restrictionCheckedStatus={[props.dietary, props.disability, props.medical]}
        options={["a) Dietary Restrictions", "b) Physical Disabilities", "c) Medical Needs"]}
        ids={["dietary", "disability", "medical"]}
        handleCheckBoxChange={props.handleCheckBoxChange}/>   
</form>  
}

function Button(props){
var style = { fontFamily: "Verdana",
             paddingLeft: "15px",
             paddingRight: "15px",
             textAlign: "center",
             borderColor: "gray"
           };
return <button onClick={() => props.submitData()}>     
  <p style={style}>{props.label}</p>
</button>
}
```

Comment: Could you post your components' code?